# Wrapfigure affects the rest of the document in environments

Tags: wrapfigure

I have encountered a strange behaviour of `wrapfigure`, that I have isolated in the following example. I don't know if it's a bug or not.

I have this latex source:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newenvironment{myenvironment}{}{}

\def\poisonousparagraph{

\begin{myenvironment}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam at rhoncus libero. Nunc auctor neque ut urna sodales vestibulum. 

\end{myenvironment}

}

\begin{document}


\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{some_picture}
  \end{center}

  \caption{Lorem ipsum}
\end{wrapfigure}



\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph



\end{document}
```

Instead of the paragraphs with `Lorem ipsum`s wrapping nicely, they are only a half-page wide in the entire document, exactly like [this](http://karelbilek.com/wtf.pdf) (link to my server with the PDF).

What, however, "fixes" the problem is making the text in `poisonousparagraph` *longer*. Or, if I delete the `myenvironment` altogether. However, in real example, I **do** need to use custom environments and I **do** need to use short text like this.

What is going on exactly?

edit: as I have tried, it has nothing to do with the picture itself, if I change it to a .png one, it still does the same thing. Also, it behaves the same when using both `latex` and `pdflatex`.

Comment: This behavior is mentioned in the documentation (which is at the end of the file [wrapfig.sty](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)): "If you put a wrapfigure in a parbox or a minipage, or any other type of grouping, the text wrapping should end before the group does".

Comment: Ah, thank you, I haven't probably read that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting at the end of `\poisonousparagraph` what the content of the internal wrapfig command `\WF@mypar` does seems to do the trick (I've replaced the image by a rule of about the same size):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newenvironment{myenvironment}{}{}

\makeatletter
\def\poisonousparagraph{

\begin{myenvironment}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam at rhoncus libero. Nunc auctor neque ut urna sodales vestibulum. 

\end{myenvironment}
\@@par
\ifnum\@@parshape=\z@ \let\WF@pspars\@empty \fi % reset `parshape'
\global\advance\c@WF@wrappedlines-\prevgraf \prevgraf\z@
\ifnum\c@WF@wrappedlines<\tw@ \WF@finale \fi

}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \rule{0.48\textwidth}{2cm}
  \end{center}

  \caption{Lorem ipsum}
\end{wrapfigure}

\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph

\end{document}
```

Comment: I absolutely don't understand why that works, but it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution from *Philippe Goutet* is perfect, but I would like to offer an easier way just FYI.

According to [wrapfig](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf) documentation

> `\linewidth` is now adjusted within the wrapped text, but since it can only be set for whole paragraphs at a time, it will persist with the wrong value after the wrapping, until the paragraph is finished.

Therefore, you would like to restart the paragraph manually by inserting `\` after your `wrapfig`, here is what you may want to do

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newenvironment{myenvironment}{}{}

\def\poisonousparagraph{

\begin{myenvironment}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam at rhoncus libero. Nunc auctor neque ut urna sodales vestibulum. 

\end{myenvironment}

}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{back.jpg}
\end{center}

\caption{Lorem ipsum}
\end{wrapfigure}
\
\

\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph
\poisonousparagraph

\end{document}
```

And here is what it looks like

> [image: warp figure]