# Flush wrapfigures in an automatic way?

Tags: wrapfigure

This is a follow up of [Typesetting errors with two wrapfigures on one page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109819/typesetting-errors-with-two-wrapfigures-on-one-page/109821?noredirect=1#comment566547_109821).

Consider the case here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\def\a{One two three four five six. }
\def\b{\a\a Red green blue yellow white black. }
\def\c{\b\b\a\b\b\b\a\b\b}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{none}
  \caption{Figure with little text}
  \label{hausdorffShapes}
\end{wrapfigure}
\b

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{none}
  \caption{Another figure here}
  \label{hausdorffBadExample}
\end{wrapfigure}
\b\b\c

\end{document}
```

which is quite a common case when I write a solution to an exercise of electronics --- quite a lot of schematics and sometime just a little of text on the side. Unfortunately, with the due warning, I have this output:

[image: Misplaced text at the side]

I can fix it like this (adding the `[3]` and the `\vspace{}` manually, by visually editing at the end).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\def\a{One two three four five six. }
\def\b{\a\a Red green blue yellow white black. }
\def\c{\b\b\a\b\b\b\a\b\b}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[3]{r}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{none}
  \caption{Figure with little text}
  \label{hausdorffShapes}
\end{wrapfigure}
\b

\vspace{4cm}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{none}
  \caption{Another figure here}
  \label{hausdorffBadExample}
\end{wrapfigure}
\b\b\c

\end{document}
```

which led to the correct (at least, in this case; I admit is not so nice) document:

[image: figure ok, lot of space, but hey...]

Is it possible to do this automatically? I mean, a `\clearwrapfigure` command that emits the necessary vertical space and restart the normal paragraph shape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this seems to work, you may prefer it with `\mbox{}` rather than `\mbox{zz}` but this shows what it is doing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\def\a{One two three four five six. }
\def\b{\a\a Red green blue yellow white black. }
\def\c{\b\b\a\b\b\b\a\b\b}

\makeatletter
\def\clearwf{\par{\count@\c@WF@wrappedlines\zz}\par}

\def\zz{{%
\ifnum\count@>\@ne
\noindent\mbox{zz}\\%
\advance\count@\m@ne
\expandafter\zz
\else
\ifhmode\unskip\unpenalty\fi
\fi}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{none}
  \caption{Figure with little text}
  \label{hausdorffShapes}
\end{wrapfigure}
\b


\clearwf

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{none}
  \caption{Another figure here}
  \label{hausdorffBadExample}
\end{wrapfigure}
\b\b\c

\end{document}
```