# Circuitikz with wrapfig problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, wrapfigure, wrap, wrapfig

I have a problem with `circuitikz`. I can't manage to display my circuits as I want to. More specifically, I can't change where the text next to the image begin, I've already tried things like `\hspace`, `\\`, `\break`, `\newline` but nothing works and `circuitikz` doesn't have much documentation as I see.
Here is my code :

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Equipe 11.97}
\lhead{Labo S3}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\title{LEPL1502 : Rapport de Laboratoire \\ Diode Zener et Circuits RC}
\date{}


\begin{document}

\maketitle\thispagestyle{fancy}

\textbf{\large  \hspace{15pt} 1. Objectif(s) :} \\ %hspace = écart du titre
\begin{itemize}
\item Compréhension du fonctionnement et des caractéristiques d’une diode Zenner. Pour ce faire, nous mesurerons la tension aux bornes de celle-ci et nous étudierons l’influence du courant.    \\
\item Compréhension du fonctionnement d’un circuit RC ainsi que de ses composantes.  \\


\end{itemize} 


\textbf{\large \hspace{15pt} 2. Rappels théoriques :}





\begin{description}[labelindent=2.5cm] %Ecart de chaque item par rapport à la marge

\item %juste un espace
%endroit où mettre les formules

\item [\large Loi d'Ohm:] $V = R*I$
\item [\large Courant dans une capa:] $I = C * DV/Dt$
\item [\large Tension dans une capa:] $V = A + B*e^-t/\tau$
\item [\large Valeurs de A et B:] $A + B = V(O)$
\item [\large Valeur de A:] $A = V(\infty)$
\item [\large Valeur de tau:] $\tau = R_{eq} * C$ 
\item %juste un espace


\end{description}

\textbf{\large \hspace{15pt} 3. Méthodes de mesures :} \\ \\ \\ \\
\textbf{\large \hspace{15pt} a) Diode Zener :}

\vspace{50pt}


\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.47\textwidth} %réglage de textwidth suivant la grandeur du circuit
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1.5cm} %grandeur des composantes

\draw (0,0)to [V, l_ = 5<\volt>, i = $I$](0,-4) to (6,-4) to [zzDo, i<= $I$, v<= VD](6,0) to [vR](3,0) to [short, -*](3,0) to [R, l_= 600<\ohm>](0,0);
%ici circuit électrique


\end{circuitikz}

\caption{Circuit Diode Zener en Backward}
\end{wrapfigure}

Mesure de la tension de seuil et de breakdown :
Nous allons faire varier le potentiomètre et ainsi calculer petit à petit à l'aide du multimètre,
les tensions et courant en mode forward (premier dessin) et en backward (deuxième dessin)


\newpage

\vspace{50pt}

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}[3]{0.47\textwidth} %réglage de textwidth suivant la grandeur du circuit
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1.5cm} %grandeur des composantes


\draw (0,0) to [vR](-3,0) to [short, -*](-3,0) to [R, l_ = 600<\ohm>](-6,0);
\draw (-6,0) to [V, l_ = 5<\volt>, i = $I$](-6,-4) to (0,-4);
\draw (0,0) to [zzDo, v^ = $VD$, i_= $I$](0,-4);



%ici circuit électrique

\end{circuitikz}

\caption{Circuit Diode Zener en Forward}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
Deuxième circuit analysé comme décrit ci-dessus sauf que cette fois, la diode est dirigée dans l'autre sens ce qui change son mode en "forward"
```

**Here I can't manage to write below the circuit.**

Note that this is one of my circuit not the whole code. Also, text is in french but this is just what is displayed, that doesn't really matter

Thanks for your kind help,
Aurélien

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Where do you want the text to begin, exactly?

Comment: Please provide the code of a *complete* document, starting with `\documentclass`  and ending with `\end{document}`. Moreover, describe what the expected result should be.

Comment: Cit: *circuitikz doesn't have much documentation as I see* --- the [200+ page manual I am maintaining](http://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf) is not enough? Anyhow, I suspect that the problem is about wrapfigure, look for example at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238683/38080

Comment: Anyway, if you post a complete, compilable example, I'll promise I'll try to help.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't notice that the answer were there, I'll provide you a full one.

Comment: @Rmano I didn't see this documentation, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `\wrapfill`.  I also highly recommend using paracol and `\splitpar`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Equipe 11.97}
\lhead{Labo S3}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\title{LEPL1502 : Rapport de Laboratoire \\ Diode Zener et Circuits RC}
\date{}

\newcommand{\wrapfill}{\par\ifnum\value{WF@wrappedlines}>0
  \addtocounter{WF@wrappedlines}{-1}%
  \null\vspace{\arabic{WF@wrappedlines}\baselineskip}%
  \WFclear
\fi}

\begin{document}

\maketitle\thispagestyle{fancy}

\textbf{\large  \hspace{15pt} 1. Objectif(s) :} \\ %hspace = écart du titre
\begin{itemize}
\item Compréhension du fonctionnement et des caractéristiques d’une diode Zenner. Pour ce faire, nous mesurerons la tension aux bornes de celle-ci et nous étudierons l’influence du courant.    \\
\item Compréhension du fonctionnement d’un circuit RC ainsi que de ses composantes.  \\


\end{itemize} 


\textbf{\large \hspace{15pt} 2. Rappels théoriques :}





\begin{description}[labelindent=2.5cm] %Ecart de chaque item par rapport à la marge

\item %juste un espace
%endroit où mettre les formules

\item [\large Loi d'Ohm:] $V = R*I$
\item [\large Courant dans une capa:] $I = C * DV/Dt$
\item [\large Tension dans une capa:] $V = A + B*e^-t/\tau$
\item [\large Valeurs de A et B:] $A + B = V(O)$
\item [\large Valeur de A:] $A = V(\infty)$
\item [\large Valeur de tau:] $\tau = R_{eq} * C$ 
\item %juste un espace


\end{description}

\textbf{\large \hspace{15pt} 3. Méthodes de mesures :} \\ \\ \\ \\
\textbf{\large \hspace{15pt} a) Diode Zener :}

\vspace{50pt}

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.47\textwidth} %réglage de textwidth suivant la grandeur du circuit
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1.5cm} %grandeur des composantes

\draw (0,0)to [V, l_ = 5<\volt>, i = $I$](0,-4) to (6,-4) to [zzDo, i<= $I$, v<= VD](6,0) to [vR](3,0) to [short, -*](3,0) to [R, l_= 600<\ohm>](0,0);
%ici circuit électrique


\end{circuitikz}

\caption{Circuit Diode Zener en Backward}
\end{wrapfigure}

Mesure de la tension de seuil et de breakdown :
Nous allons faire varier le potentiomètre et ainsi calculer petit à petit à l'aide du multimètre,
les tensions et courant en mode forward (premier dessin) et en backward (deuxième dessin)

\wrapfill
\newpage

\vspace{50pt}

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.47\textwidth} %réglage de textwidth suivant la grandeur du circuit
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1.5cm} %grandeur des composantes


\draw (0,0) to [vR](-3,0) to [short, -*](-3,0) to [R, l_ = 600<\ohm>](-6,0);
\draw (-6,0) to [V, l_ = 5<\volt>, i = $I$](-6,-4) to (0,-4);
\draw (0,0) to [zzDo, v^ = $VD$, i_= $I$](0,-4);



%ici circuit électrique

\end{circuitikz}

\caption{Circuit Diode Zener en Forward}
\end{wrapfigure}
\wrapfill
\end{document}
```