# Wrap figure interfering with text

Tags: wrapfigure

I wanted to wrap my figure and just write text around it but this happens:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
\subsection{Príklad č.2}
\textbf{Zadanie:} Na obrázku \ref{koleno} je znázornené koleno.\\

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.40\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{uloha2.png} 
\caption{Koleno (zdroj: Zadania bonusových príkladov )}
\label{koleno}

\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{tabular}{l l}
 $D_1 = 20 \quad mm$   & $p= 49 900 \quad Pa $\\
 $D_2 = 10 \quad mm$   & $V_k =1.8 \cdot 10^{-5} \quad m^3$\\ 
 $H = 0.1 \quad m$ & $\rho = 998 \quad kg\cdot m^{-3}$ \\
 $h = 25 \quad mm$ &  $g = 9.81 \quad m \cdot s^{-1}$\\
\end{tabular}

\\ Vypočítať: 
\begin{itemize}
   \item Silu $\Vec{F_K}$ pôsobiacu na koleno (vzťah odvodiť z vety o zmene hybnosti)
   \item Odvodiť vzťah závislosti priemeru paprsku na súradnici z. Predpokladá sa, že paprsok je celú dobu kompaktný a nerozkladá sa.
   \item Silu pôsobiacu na dosku.
\end{itemize}
\subsubsection{BR 2 (výstup z kolena) - 3 (vrchol paprsku)}
\begin{equation}
\frac{p}{\rho} + \frac{{v_2}^2}{2} + gh_2 = \frac{p_3}{\rho} + \frac{{v_3}^2}{2} + gh_3
\end{equation}
Tlak okolia je konštantný, takže mi vypadne z rovnice tlaková potencionálna energia na vrchole paprsku. Taktiež mi vypadne kinetická merná energia na vrchole paprsku, pretože tam je už všetka spotrebovaná. 
\begin{equation*}
   \frac{p}{\rho} + \frac{{v_2}^2}{2} + gh_2 = gh_3
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{{v_2}^2}{2} = g (h_3 - h_2 ) - \frac{p}{\rho}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
v_2 = \sqrt{2 \cdot (g \cdot H - \frac{p}{\rho}) }
\end{equation*}
```

Do you know what's the problem ? thanks

Comment: Unrelated to the issue itself, but you might want to take a look at the `siunitx` package in order to improve the typesetting of numbers and their units.

Comment: thank you so much, I am still learning LaTex. Good to know !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When things that are not plain text are present,  the automatic calculations of the figure space is often wrong. You can do two things:

1. In this case, you have a lot of white space above. Try adding a `\vspace*{-1.5cm}` (or whatever) before the `\includegraphics`.
2. say explicitly to `wrapfig` how many lines you want to skip. You have to use the optional argument:

   ```
   \begin{wrapfigure}[16]{r}
   ```

   adjusting the `16` more or less by try and error (LaTeX is not really though for wrapfigures, I fear).

If you had posted a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), I could have tried it...

Comment: Thank you, it worked. but now the rest of the page is like this. Like if there would be a figure there or something

Comment: oh I cant post an image to a commment. like the text is all just on the left side of the page

Comment: Yes, change the 16 until you got your result... it's difficult to tell if you don't prepare a MWE. Also, there is very interesting info here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238680/flush-wrapfigures-in-an-automatic-way

Answer (score 2):

Probably this alternative, that uses two minipages instead of `wrapfig` also suits your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\subsection{Príklad č.2}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
\textbf{Zadanie:} Na obrázku \ref{koleno} je znázornené koleno.
\[
\begin{aligned}
 D_1 &= \SI{20}{\mm}   & p    &= \SI{49 900}{\Pa}          \\
 D_2 &= \SI{10}{\mm}   & V_k  &= \SI{1.8e-5}{\cubic\m}     \\ 
 H   &= \SI{0.1}{\m}   & \rho &= \SI{998}{\kg\per\cubic\m} \\
 h   &= \SI{25}{\mm}   & g    &= \SI{9.81}{\m\per\s}       \\
\end{aligned}
\]
 Vypočítať: 
\begin{itemize}
   \item Silu $\Vec{F_K}$ pôsobiacu na koleno (vzťah odvodiť z vety o zmene hybnosti)
   \item Odvodiť vzťah závislosti priemeru paprsku na súradnici z. Predpokladá sa, že paprsok je celú dobu kompaktný a nerozkladá sa.
   \item Silu pôsobiacu na dosku.
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-10x16} 
\captionof{figure}{Koleno (zdroj: Zadania bonusových príkladov )}
\label{koleno}
\end{minipage}

\subsubsection{BR 2 (výstup z kolena) - 3 (vrchol paprsku)}
\begin{equation}
\frac{p}{\rho} + \frac{{v_2}^2}{2} + gh_2 = \frac{p_3}{\rho} + \frac{{v_3}^2}{2} + gh_3
\end{equation}
Tlak okolia je konštantný, takže mi vypadne z rovnice tlaková potencionálna energia na vrchole paprsku. Taktiež mi vypadne kinetická merná energia na vrchole paprsku, pretože tam je už všetka spotrebovaná. 
\begin{align*}
\frac{p}{\rho} + \frac{{v_2}^2}{2} + gh_2 &= gh_3    \\
\frac{{v_2}^2}{2} &= g (h_3 - h_2 ) - \frac{p}{\rho} \\
v_2 &= \sqrt{2 \cdot (g \cdot H - \frac{p}{\rho}) }
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```