# Wrapfig in latex for placing images and text in a proper way

Tags: wrapfig

I am trying to place my text and image using `wrapfig` in Latex. However, I am not able to follow the syntax properly, and thus getting a dis-oriented alignment.

```
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\heading{Safe SSL}
    
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{8cm}
    \caption{Safe SSL check}\label{wrap-fig:1}
    \includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{SafeSSL.png}
    \end{wrapfigure} 
    
    {We trained both the semi-supervised and supervised models by splitting the data with varying test set sizes and then compared the efficiency of SSL to the supervised approach and concluded that the "Safe SSL" assumption holds as it performed better for the semi-supervised model at the split test data.
    \par}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

I get the following result rendered. Any fixes to this?

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem.

Comment: What is `\heading{}`? Probably you need @DavidCarlisle `\clearwf` here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238683/38080

Comment: it is complicated to make wrapfig work with paragraphs that start in a group, why do you have a group round the text `We trained....` ?

Comment: please make an example that is a complete document, you can use `example-image` as the image as it is available for tests.   It is very hard to guess the issue just from a fragment.

Comment: does the code really produce the output you show? you specify a rather wide cut-out of 8cm so the text would be in a very narrow column unless you have a very wide page. Then you specify a much smaller image width of 5.5cm so there should be 2.5cm of white space to the right of the image (which is shown in your output) so your text with is ~30cm or so?