# How to make a break text off from wrapping around figure

Tags: wrapfigure

I'm using {wrapfigure} but I don't have enough text to completely wrap a figure. I only want a certain paragraph to wrap a figure and then create a new paragraph below this to continue as usual i.e

```
 
[-------------------------]    
                            Begin Text 1.

 
          figure

                            End Text 1.

[-------------------------]


Text 2.
```

But instead my Text 1. and Text 2. are both wrapping around the figure. I have tried using \vspace{}, but this just moves my Text 2. down while still being indented as if it was wrapping around the figure.

Comment: Maybe David's solution here  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238680/ ?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526518/wrapfigure-two-figures-left-and-right-with-text-in-between

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!